# Определение функции what() в собственном классе исключения

Tags: c++

```
class derivedexception: public exception {
      virtual const char* what() const throw() {
        return "My derived exception";
      }
} myderivedexception;
```

Зачем в функции what() в конце стоит throw()? Что это означает?

Update: Я нашел ответ на английском StackOverflow, но не уверен что правильно его понял. Это значит что метод не может вызвать исключений?

Answer (score 1):

Это означает что функция никогда не вызовет исключений.

Запись `throw()` является устаревшей, вместо неё необходимо использовать спецификатор `noexcept`

Comment: и зачем вы спрашиваете, если знаете ответ?

Comment: Опишите тогда уж, что произойдет, если внутри try catch конструкции бросится исключение

Comment: Отвечать на собственные вопросы без одобрения со стороны других участников на стековерфлоу - это дурной тон. И "функция никогда не вызовет исключений" немного неточная формулировка. Во-первый, компилятор выдаст предупреждение, если в функции будет throw. Во-вторых, будет вызван terminate, если такое произойдёт, даже если вы всё обернёте в try catch